# Application can not run in newest browser

Tags: java, glassfish, certificate

I have some problem with glassfish certificate.

I have two environment here, let's say environment A and environment B.
I deploy same application in that two environment. But when i try to run the application with latest version of chrome and firefox, i cant't open my application in environment B. But, i able to run the application in environment A, with same application.

I had try to copy the glassfish from environment B to environment A, i able to run the application within the glassfish that i had copy from environment B in environment A, otherwise, i can't run the application within the glassfish that i had copy from environment A to environment B.

I wonder how to solve this problem. Did glassfish certificate had some effect for this problem?

Maybe someone can help me to solve this problem. Thanks before

Comment: Please add details on what happens when you can't open your application. Is there any error message? Is there just a timeout? There's a very very large number of things that could cause this, so some more concrete details are needed to narrow things down.

Comment: @Mike when i try to run the application in environment B, i got error something like SSL FALLBACK in chrome, but no error message in firefox